# Rails admin suddenly stopped working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site online that currently uses rails admin and is what I have been using to track the users and other metrics for the site. However today when I went to my site I suddenly get a 500 internal error when I visit /admin. I have not updated or changed my code in a while so I can not for the life of me figure out whats going wrong.

Here is the error from the heroku logs:

```
2015-04-22T04:38:57.431281+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin" for 
108.162.249.51 at 2015-04-22 04:38:57 +0000
2015-04-22T04:38:57.435082+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2015-04-22T04:38:57.436300+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-22T04:38:57.436302+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass):
2015-04-22T04:38:57.436304+00:00 app[web.1]:   config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
2015-04-22T04:38:57.436306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-22T04:38:57.434381+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
2015-04-22T04:38:57.436305+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

It works locally so I dont know what is happening. Also here is the code from that error:

```
#config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:4
redirect_to main_app.root_path unless warden.user.admin
```

I checked the console as well and that account still has admin active

Comment: Did you visit /admin without being authentified maybe ?

Comment: no i am definitely logged in if thats what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`warden.user` isn't being set. I would change the code to

`redirect_to main_app.root_path unless warden.user.try(:admin)`

Comment: ok is there a reason though why this would just suddenly stop working and why that line of code works on development? As in the previous line of code worked fine until today and I havent updated it since. I will give your code a go though

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. 

`NoMethodError (undefined method admin for nil:NilClass):` means that you are calling the `admin` method on nil, and so that means `warden.user` is nil -- but why that is, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah its really confusing. Regardless, your code worked - thanks!